# Using HighChart JS files locally

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, highcharts, external-script

I'm trying to use the highchats js files locally in code. When I use the official link as below it is working

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 310px; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

When I tried same as a local imported file as below it is not working

```
<script src="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/resources/js/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/resources/js/highcharts-more.js"></script> 
<script src="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/resources/js/highcharts.js"></script>
```

the below is the error i'm facing

[image]

Is it possible to use locally or if i keep those files in my server will it help.

Comment: Are you sure the local files are properly inserted? [Error 17](http://www.highcharts.com/errors/17) probably means they aren't.

Comment: I have i'm able to open the script file on clicking the links in browser which is displayed in page source

Comment: You could also try drawing your charts in document ready(if you already aren't), just to make sure the files are inserted. Can't think of anything else.

Comment: Please *avoid* pictures where text will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the order is important when you are loading libraries. Try this:

```
   <script src="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/resources/js/highcharts.js"></script>
  <script src="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/resources/js/highcharts-more.js"></script> 
    <script src="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/resources/js/exporting.js">    </script>
```